# How to query on Dataset

Tags: c#, xml

The dataset have tables and columns details got from the XML file.I want to query the dataset and get the data into a datatable using C# code.The query consists of filter criteria,relations,groupby,aggregate function and expression.

The following code is used to execute query in MSAccess: Kindly suggest me a method that can do the same with dataset.

```
public override DataTable ExecuteQuery(DBProperties dbpro, string Query)
        {
                string query = Query;
                conn = new OleDbConnection(dbpro.ConnectionString);
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(datatable);
                    return datatable;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the buildin [Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx).

Linq doesn't work that well on ADO objects.

Comment: @Jasper: could you go through the above code and suggest a similar nethod to query the dataset using C# code.

Comment: datatable.Select("customerid='123'"); Or datatable.Select("customerid='123'", "productid='456'");

Answer (score 0):

Use the "new" [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) extensions introduced to .NET

Comment: can you suggest any other method apart from LINQ as we are not using it.

Comment: @psobhan - why not? it makes a lot of this very easy and pleasant to program.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnur - Ok how is it to execute query on dataset using LINQ.